# how to grab all jpg files recursively using shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell

so whenever I put a directory as my first argument, I want my program to grab all the jpg files and sort them in the order they are created. I have more than one sub-directories so I need the process to be done recursively. 
Here's what I tried

```
#!/bin/bash
file = "$1"
find $1 -name '*.jpg'
sor...
```

really not sure how to approach...any help would be appreciated

Comment: [BashFAQ #3](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) (*How can I sort or compare files based on some metadata attribute (newest / oldest modification time, size, etc)?*) and [UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) are both very relevant.

Comment: If "$1" is worth quoting in line 2, it probably should be worth quoting in line 3.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: `find "$1" -type f -name '*.jpg' -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n`

Comment: It's going to be hard to sort them in the order they were created, unless you consistently store that data somewhere (e.g. if all your JPEG files have EXIF `DateTimeDigitized` tags).  Otherwise, all you have is last modification time or inode change time; standard Unix-family file systems have no concept of *creation* time.

Answer (score -1):

You give a path and file type,this code find :)
You can save as FindFileScript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Which directory should I search ? (/Desktop) : "
read directory
echo -n "Select file type(like png || jpg || pdf) : "
read fileType
find "$directory" -type f -name "*.$fileType"
./FindFileScript.sh
```